Problema con los estilos CSS al desplegar proyecto React en Vercel
estoy intentando desplegar mi portfolio con React en Vercel pero no me esta aplicando un estilo especifico el cual es:
animation-timeline: view();

En el servidor de desarrollo local lo ejecuta sin ningun problema, el inconveniente es al desplegarlo en vercel, cuando inspecciono el navegador, ese estilo especifico me sale tachado y opaco, algo asi:

Este es el codigo CSS que estoy intentando ejecutar:
.skills,
.aboutMe,
.portfolio,
.educationExp,
.contact {
  animation: scroll-reveal linear both;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-reveal linear both;
  animation-timeline: view();
  animation-range: entry 30% cover 35%;
  scroll-margin-top: 50vh;
}

@keyframes scroll-reveal {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    translate: 0 20vh;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    translate: 0 0;
  }
}


El código que intentas ejecutar no se corresponde con el código mostrado en la captura de pantalla de las herramientas del desarrollador.

No entiendo? Cual es la parte que no coincide?

El orden no coincide. Y en CSS el orden es importante y afecta el resultado. En al código compartido, muestras animation y -webkit-animation arriba y animation-timeline y animation-range abajo (esto va a funcionar correctamente). Pero en la captura de pantalla, los estilos están en un orden diferente que van a hacer que fallen: animation-timeline primero y luego los demás. Como animation y -webkit-animation son shorthands que incluyen animation-timeline, el valor que das se sobreescribe y no se tiene en cuenta.

En CSS el orden de las propiedades en el código es muy importante. El código que compartes en la pregunta no se corresponde con el código que se muestra en la captura de las herramientas.
En el código:

animation
-webkit-animation
animation-timeline
animation-range

Pero en la captura de pantalla, el orden es diferente:

animation-timeline
animation-range
animation
-webkit-animation

Ahora, animation y -webkit-animation son shorthands, es decir propiedades que incluyen valores para múltiples propiedades... y en este caso, hace que los valores de animation-timeline se reseteen como se indica en la página de MDN.
Al poner los shorthands al final sin especificar el valor de animation-timeline, el valor se sobreescribirá con el valor por defecto y perderás lo que has puesto.
Posibles soluciones:

No uses shorthands y pon los valores que quieres de forma individual (animation-name, animation-timing-function y animation-fill-mode respectivamente):
 animation-name: scroll-reveal;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-timeline: view();
 animation-range: entry 30% cover 35%;


Asegúrate de que las definiciones están en el orden correcto:
 animation: scroll-reveal linear both;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-reveal linear both;
 animation-timeline: view();
 animation-range: entry 30% cover 35%;



¿Por qué los valores que comparten no coinciden con los valores en el navegador? Eso ya no lo sé. El navegador o los frameworks no van a reordenar el CSS porque saben de la importancia del orden en ese lenguaje. ¿Quizás probaste algo antes y se quedó en la caché?

Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pude resolverlo dando los valores individuales de la animacion como lo explicaste en la primera solucion:
{
animation-name: scroll-reveal;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-timeline: view();
animation-range: entry 30% cover 35%;
scroll-margin-top: 50vh;
}
El problema es que en el Deploy sigue cambiando el orden de los valores por alguna razon, estoy trabajando con react, no se si tenga algo que ver.

De todas maneras me funciono, aunque cambie el orden de las propiedades en el deploy funciona correctamente.
